# multiply large numbers in fastest way of multiplication

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, multiplication, bigint

```
// the function returns the multiply of p1 and p2 big
function mul_b(p1, p2) {
    var eql = ""; // fine value 
    var r_eql = ""; // reversed value retured
    var carry = 0;
    var length_p1 = p1.length - 1;
    console.log( "length first number " + length_p1);
    var length_p2 = p2.length - 1;
    console.log( "length secnd number " + length_p2);       
    if (length_p1 != length_p2){// eql two number by padding zeros
        return "Please make both sides equal!";
    }
    console.log(length_p1 + "=" + length_p2);       
    var A1,A2;
    var A3 = 0;
    for(var j = length_p1; j>=0; j--){
        var k = j;
        A3 = 0;
        for( var i = length_p1 ; i >= j ; i-- ){            
            A1 = parseInt(p1.charAt(k));
            A2 = parseInt(p2.charAt(i));
            k+=1;
            console.log("("+A1+","+A2+")");
            A3 = (A1 * A2) + A3;    
            console.log("("+A3+")");
        }
        eql = A3.toString().concat(eql);
        console.log("("+eql+")"); 
    }
    for(var j = (length_p1-1); j>=0; j--){
        var k = j;
        A3 = 0;
        for( var i = 0; i<=j; i++ ){            
            A1 = parseInt(p1.charAt(k));
            A2 = parseInt(p2.charAt(i));
            k-=1;
            console.log("("+A1+","+A2+") " + k + " , "+ i);
            A3 = (A1 * A2)+A3;  
            console.log("("+A3+")");
        }
        eql = A3.toString().concat(eql);
        console.log("("+eql+")");
    }
    var f_eql = "";
    f_eql = eql.charAt(0);
    for (var i = 1; i<=(eql.length); i++){
        if (eql.charAt(i+1) == ""){
            f_eql += (parseInt(eql.charAt(i)) + carry + 0).toString();
        }else{
            if ((parseInt(eql.charAt(i)) + parseInt(eql.charAt(i+1)) + carry)<10){//carry
                f_eql += (parseInt(eql.charAt(i)) + parseInt(eql.charAt(i+1))+ carry).toString();
                carry = 0;
            } else {
                f_eql += (parseInt(eql.charAt(i)) + parseInt(eql.charAt(i+1)) - 10).toString();
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
        console.log("("+eql.charAt(i)+")"+eql.charAt(i+1));
        i += 1;
    }
    console.log("fine = ("+eql+")");
    console.log("("+f_eql+")"); 
    return   f_eql;          
}
```

please, i getting error with carry and make me headache, where my error? and is this code cool or what it's new method to multiply two big number by me it's called triangle multiplication.

when i'm try multiply

123456789012 --- 12 digit by

### 123456789012 --- 12 digit

141020355684120165200226244249240216176119445036144

my method is

the first digit put down 
and the second added to third and put down 
and the forth added to fifth and put down
and etc to finial digit

but i'm missing error in carry 
So please help my?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an interactive example

```js
$(function() {
  var update = function() {
    var itemA = $("#nrA").val();
    var itemB = $("#nrB").val();
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var result = new BigNumber(itemA).multiply(itemB.toString())
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var total = end - start;
    $("#fact").val(result);
    $("#time").val(total + " ms");
  };
  $("#nrA").on("input", function() {
    update();
  });
  $("#nrB").on("input", function() {
    update();
  });
  update();
});
```

```css
#fact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/61473108321/bignumber.js"></script>
<label for="nrA">Number A:</label>
<input id="nrA" value="100"></input>
<label for="nrB">Number B:</label>
<input id="nrB" value="100"></input><br/>
<label for="fact">A * B:</label><br/>
<textarea id="fact"></textarea><br/>
<label for="time">Computed in:</label>
<input id="time"></input>
```

Comment: Note that fastest way would be to use hardware supported bignum multiplication. If you want second fastest with minimal effort I would use Mathematica/Wolfram and compile the code to C and run that. Other then that GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library would yield really good results. If you want faster results then that you need to higher a coder.

Comment: Nice Code @margus But i need the error in my code my method new and nice to try thank you your answer so helpful.

Comment: Your solution is wrong and slowest possible solution you can make without intentionally making it slow. Unless you need your effort I would just scrap everything.

Comment: Dude you are amazing your code too its really cool actually i need it to break RSA 2048 bit, 2048 = 589 digits so that is public key made from 1024 = 245 digit prime multiply by 245 digit prime so it's breakable by fastest multiplication. thanks again you are so helpful remember RSA is breakable for 100000000 $ so we trying to make it free.

Comment: @BilalSaad: If you don't know how to multiply bignums, you don't have any concept of how hard a 2048-bit factorization is. The most advanced algorithm in the world couldn't do it with all the world's computers running for a thousand years, even before you get to the linear algebra step which is insurmountable for a number of that size -- there isn't a large enough computer on Earth to hold the relations matrix.

Comment: @Charles: When I complete it I will give you a link to it that right if we thinking like computers we can't reach the goal but when we rethink again we will find too many solutions we've missed, RSA it's Breakable because it's rely on Prime number and the prime number rely on 7 by equation so it's easy to break.